# Getting error code when creating a socket in Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm doing some socket programming in Linux and am wondering how to get the error code when the function socket(...); fails.

for example for the "getaddrinfo" function i can do this:

```
//Resolve the server address and port
    result = (struct addrinfo *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    iResult = getaddrinfo("google.com", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0){
        printf("%d\n", iResult);
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo failed: %s\n", gai_strerror(iResult));
        getchar();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

However I want to do a similar thing using socket(...) function.

According to this: 
http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket

the function returns -1 on failure, and sets errno to the appropriate error number. How do i access this "errno" though?
This is my code so far:

```
int connectSocket = 0;
connectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
printf("%d\n", connectSocket);

if (connectSocket == -1){
    printf("socket failed with error: %s\n", error_string); //TODO: HELP DECLARING error_string
    getchar();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: See `errno(3)` and `strerror(3)` manual pages.

Comment: DO NOT allocate memory for the `addrinfo` that you pass in the last parameter of `getaddrinfo()`. It will allocate the `addrinfo` for you, which you pass to `freeaddrinfo()` to free it: `result = NULL; iResult = getaddrinfo(..., &result); if (iResult == 0) { ...; freeaddrinfo(result); }`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`errno` is a thread-local global variable, defined in [`<errno.h>`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html). The man page for many library functions will indicate that they return -1 on error, and set `errno`.

You can convert an `errno` value to a useful string with the [`strerror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) function.

In general, you should code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) {
    int s;

    s = socket(...);
    if (s < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, glibc's [`printf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) and friends support a `%m` format specifier, which is replaced with `strerror(errno)` (no argument is needed). So the above example could be replaced with:

```
    if (s < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed: %m\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

And to make it all simpler, there is the [`perror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) function, which prints out a message similar to above.

```
    if (s < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
```

Wrapping it all up - error handling need not be complex and verbose.  Putting the socket call and the test for `< 0` in one statement, the above code could look like this, and you'll be a real UNIX pro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) {
    int s;

    if ((s = socket(...)) < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oddly enough: "fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));" didn't seem to work! Instead it would just exit the program. But all the rest did! Many Thanks!

Comment: nit: `#define errno (*__get_errno())` would be legal, it's not necessarily a variable, it's a macro "which expands to a modifiable lvalue that has type `int` and thread local storage".

Answer (score 5):

Add `#include <errno.h>` and you'll be able to read the global `errno` variable.

```
connectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (connectSocket < 0) {
    if (errno == EACCESS) ...
```

You can use `perror` in `stdio.h` to print an error message based on the value of `errno` or you can use `strerror` in `string.h` to access a string describing the error code

```
connectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (connectSocket < 0) {
    perror("socket");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```